# How can you display rows in 'dynamic' sizes using tableview of Corona SDK

Tags: height, tableview, coronasdk

I am using tableview to display a list of items
e.g.

```
list = 
[
   {name='bob',
    description='really long description that can be multiple rows',
    image='an image from my server',
    },
    ...
]
```

the above is just an example. I got my data from my server, including images of variable sizes. My question is how do I display the correct row size(height) once I got image from the server. I understand that I can wait until all data and image has been downloaded from server. Then precompute the height. But I want to be able to display the text first (as texts are more likely to be firstly downloaded), then once there is an image in it, I download it again. After the image is downloaded, I want to resize the row height. How can I do that?

Comment: Populate the tableview using only names.  Then load the images and call a function that traverses through the rows in your tableview, adding the appropriate image to each.  You may need to call this function after some delay to allow time for the images to load.

Comment: what i want to do is to display names and description first in the rows. Because images take sometime to load, I 'd like to refresh the size (height) of the rows after images are downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a multi-line display.newText() of the width you expect to put in the table view. When the object is created, grab it's height and then remove the object. Use that height + some padding for the row height.  There may be performance issues with this, so as an alternate, keep the text object and pass it in as a parameter when you create the row.

Comment: Wow. Thanks Rob. Read many of your post in the forum and corona website :) I actually did exactly what you mentioned. However, I did it in more sophiscated way, because I also have both texts and images from the server. So I read use your methods to do texts first and display them in the row, but for the images, I keep an 'appropriate' space for the image and display 'reading image from server' in that space. I then download the images. This way, the texts get displayed first without needing to wait for the long image download.